# Dynamics CRM 2011 - How to relate two different entities

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have two different custom entities. The first one (payment) I create manually using a form. When the payment is created it executes a plugin that will create one or more vouchers. The plugin creates the voucher without a problem. The problem is when I go to the payment and click on vouchers, I don't see the voucher I just created listed. If I go look at all the vouchers I can see the one I just created. There is a 1 to many relationship from payment to voucher. What do I need to do in my plugin for the entities to be related?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you just haven't setup the relationship back to the triggering payment when you create the voucher.

Given the 1:N relationship and since you're creating the voucher in the context of a payment plugin you can set the lookup on the voucher to the payment for which the plugin is currently executing (target).

```
new_voucher.new_paymentid = new EntityReference(...);
```

`new_paymentid` is the lookup attribute on voucher (obviously it'll be called something else in your case).  For the `EntityReference` you'll need to define the EntityName and Id of the product, which you can read from the target.